# RectangleF contains always returns false

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am using `RectangleF.Contains(PointF)` and it is always returning false.

Example Code:

```
  RectangleF bounds = RectangleF.FromLTRB(-180, 90, 180, -90);
  bounds.Contains(new PointF(0, 0);
```

I am trying to get this quadtree [link](https://bluetoque.ca/products/quadtree/) library to work in Unity.
I used the System.Drawing.dll from the Mono folder

The quadtree is going to be used to store latitude and longitude values.

Is it an issue with the bounds? Or is it something else?

Comment: What is RectangleF? Unity calles this struct Rect

Comment: @zambari I am using System.Drawing not UnityEngine.UI this is a .net class

Comment: The `unity3d` tag is missleading.

Comment: @RenéVogt This seems to have fixed the issue can you elaborate more. Why the top and bottom are reversed?

Comment: The first monitors were pure text monitors consisting of fixed rows and columns containing one single character per cell. Since text lines run from top to bottom they were numbered this way. This was later adopted for the y-coordinates of the graphics adapters as well to retain some degree of compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
bounds = RectangleF.FromLTRB(-180, 90, 180, -90);
```

You create an empty (or event "negative") rectangle. The y-coordinates work here like screen coordinates ascending from top to bottom.

So define the rectangle as

```
bounds = RectangleF.FromLTRB(-180, -90, 180, 90);
```

and `bounds.Contains(new PointF(0, 0);` will return `true`;

Comment: Do you have a link or can you explain more how the screen coordinates work. And why does RectangleF follows that.

Comment: @LonsomeHell can't remember any docs on this topic, it's just common: Screen coordinates ascend from upper left to lower right. `RectangleF` does this, because it's part of `System.Drawing`, a namespace containing methods to draw, and for drawing we use this orientation. Don't know who decided that, but it's been like that since I started coding 25 years ago.

Comment: That makes sense if it is part of screen drawing Apis. I was treating it like a graph geometry API.